# Need to change a string to binary, then to ASCII

Tags: c++, c, bluetooth, binary, ascii

I have some data coming in from a sensor. The data is in the range of a signed int, 16 bits or so. I need to send the data out via Bluetooth.

Problem:

The data is -1564, lets say.The Bluetooth transmits -, 1, 5, 6, then 4. This is inefficient. I can process the data on the PC later, I just need the frequency to go up.

My Idea/ Solution:

Have it convert to binary, then to ASCII for output. I can convert the ASCII later in processing. I have the binary part (found on StackOverflow) here:

```
inline void printbincharpad(char c)
{
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        putchar( (c & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0' );
    }
}
```

This outputs in binary very well. But getting the bluetooth to transmit, say 24, spits out 1, 1, 0, 0, then 0. In fact, slower than just 2, then 4.

Say I have 65062, 5 bytes to transmit, coming out of the sensor. That is 1111111000100110 in binary, 16 bytes. To ASCII, it's �& (yes, the character set here is small, I know, but it's unique) just 2 bytes! In HEX it's FE26, 4 bytes. A savings of 3 vs decimal and 14 vs. binary and 2 vs. Hex. Ok, obviously, I want ASCII sent out here.

My Question:

So, how do I convert to ASCII if given a binary input?
I want to send that, the ASCII

Hedging:

Yes, I code in MatLab more than C++. This is for a microcontroller. The BAUD is 115200. No, I don't know how the above code works, I don't know where putchar's documentation is found. If you knw of a library that I need to run this, please tell me, as I do not know.

Thank you for any and all help or advice, I do appreciate it.

EDIT: In response to some of the comments: it's two 16 bit registers I am reading from, so data loss is impossible.

Comment: This is not really a "ASCII" problem...and putchar is only a function for printing the value to the console (docs can be easily found in google, by the way). You´re saying you don´t understand the code, that´s ok, but: To get a suitable solution, please explain where the data comes from (in the code, which variable type/function/...) and where it should go after converting.

Comment: I don't see what the problem with the existing transmission as "-1564", that's going to cover your entire range of values using only 6 characters. The only way you are going to make it more efficient is to transmit as 4 hexadecimal characters - I would not try sending just 2 bytes as you may well get strange effects with some byte values.

Comment: Can't you just send a `short` between the two and avoid all of these conversions? That would just be two bytes...

Comment: Do you know if your serial link can handle arbitrary binary data? What happens when it looks like control characters or escape sequences? Also, being pedantic, "ASCII" is 7 bits per character - 8 bits needs to be interpreted as some extended codepage or UTF-8.

Comment: It's not obvious at all *why* you want ASCII sent out, rather than the original two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you say ASCII, you mean Base 256. You can search for solutions to converting from Base 10 to Base 256.

Here is a C program that converts an string containing 65062 (5 characters) to a string of 2 characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    char* inputString="65062";
    int input;
    char* tmpString;
    char* outString;
    int Counter;

    input = atoi(inputString);
    outString= malloc (sizeof(input) + 1);
    tmpString = &input;

    for (Counter=0; Counter < sizeof(input) ; Counter++) {
        outString[Counter] = tmpString[Counter];
    }

    outString[sizeof(input)] = '\0';

    printf ("outString = %s\n", outString);

    free(outString);
}
```

Comment: Be sure to `free()` outString. You should also return a value such as `return 0;` at the end of `main()`.

Comment: Just for fun, how about: `char outString[3]={0}; memcpy(outString, &input, 2);`?

Comment: This doesn't 'convert' anything. It just copies *four* bytes (not 2), and then appends a trailing null. Completely pointless. -1

Comment: EJP, The int is 2 or 4 bytes depending on hardware. This code takes each byte and appends it to the outString. By the end of it, you have a string with 2 chars. The null is added so that printf can work.

Comment: There is no conversion here. By the end of it you have the same two or four bytes of binary that you started with plus a terminating null. It's not a string that you can pass to `printf().` Consider the value 0x0001 for example. Your code converts that to a string of zero characters. And `printf()` isn't mentioned in the question. And using `malloc()` is unnecessary, and you've left out the `free().` And so on. It's futile.

Comment: The input in the question is 16 bits of binary, not a string. Your new code still doesn't produce anything that can be properly described as a string at all. Still complete useless and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[putchar](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/) writes to the [standard output](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdout/), which is usually the console.

You may take a look at the other output functions in the [cstdio (or stdio.h)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/) library.

Anyways, using `putchar()`, here's one way to achieve what you're asking for:

```
void print_bytes (int n)
{
    char *p = (char *) &n ;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof (n); ++i) {
        putchar (p [i]) ;
    }
}
```

If you know for certain that you only want 16 bits from the integer, you can simplify this like this:

```
void print_bytes (int n)
{
    char b = n & 0xff ;
    char a = (n >> 8) & 0xff ;

    putchar (a) ;
    putchar (b) ;
}
```

Comment: perfect! This works great for me! Thank you very very much! Now, off to understand putchar() better! Again, many thanks!

Comment: @user3320919 If this worked for you, feel free to upvote it and mark it as an answer.